# How to compare compressors of different efficiencies and pressure ratios?

Tags: compressor

I have two different engines, the CFM56, and the CFM LEAP-X. I roughly know the design point (take-off) isentropic efficiency and the pressure ratio for the LPC/HPC for both of them which are different from one another and can be provided as an input in a program.

I want to compare the compressor pressure ratio of the engines in the off-design (cruise) condition, which I believe will again have different pressure ratios and efficiencies. Can I somehow directly compare the pressure ratios of the two compressors? Do I need to have similar efficiencies to make such a comparison? Also, what role does polytropic efficiency play in this?

Comment: These engines are from 2 different era's, two different designs. CFM56 has BPR of 5-6 and OPR of about 32, the LEAP has a BPR of 9-11 and an OPR of about 40. Why do you want to compare the 2 compressors? Maybe you could explain that better in the question.

Comment: Are you sure the design point is takeoff?  I'm not a compressor guy, but I'm pretty sure the aero design point is cruise, and takeoff would be considered off-design.  Because you are at cruise for hours and hours, and takeoff for only a few minutes, so efficiency at cruise becomes the most important thing.

Comment: @DanielK In many gas turbine simulation software packages there is something called a design point, but, this should be referred to as reference point. Usually the most data we can find is on the take-off point hence the confusion of design point, it is the design/reference point of the software model, not the actual design point.